# What is a Huffman tree for a Block-Code?

Tags: data-structures, trees, binary-trees, huffman-coding

We have the word "w = aabceefgeebdaabbceeffghdcbbeefbbbbghhie ".

I have created a Huffman tree for the string w.

We get the following table:

[image]

Now I want to create a Huffman tree for a Block-Code with length of block $4$.

Do we maybe take each consecutive 4 letters, i.e., {aabc, eefg, eebd, aabb, ceef, fghd, cbbe, efbb, bbgh, hie} to make the tree?

But then the last one is of length 3 and not 4.

So, do we choose in an other way the blocks?

Answer (score 1):

In your context, a block code of length $\ell$ encodes $\ell$ letters at a time. The domain thus consists of all words over the alphabet of length $\ell$. Unless you're told otherwise, the assumption is that the individual letters are independent - the probability of a word $\sigma_1 \dots \sigma_\ell$ is the product of the probabilities of the individual letters.

Comment: So do we have to find all the possible words with 4 letters and then we create the tree considering these words as the symbols?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: The words: "befa" and "efba" are counted as the same word, or not?

Comment: The idea of the block code is to encode streams of letters more efficiently than one letter at a time. Given this rationale, you should be able to answer this question yourself. If you have any further questions, I suggest asking your TA or instructor.

Comment: I am not taking that subject,... I am trying to learn it by myself, by looking at some examples/notes of the internet... Unfortunately, I haven't found an example for a Huffman tree for a block code.... So, do we have the following block? $$$$ 
idcf, idca, idce, idcb, idch, idcg, dcgh, dcgf, dcga, dcge, dcgb, cghf, cgha, cghe, cghb, ghfa, ghfe, ghfb, hfae, hfab, faeb $$$$ How do we know if we have found all the possibilities?

Comment: We have $9^4$ possibilities right?

Comment: Is it possible to make a tree with $6561$ elements?

Comment: We have the word "w = aabceefgeebdaabbceeffghdcbbeefbbbbghhie ". 
Do we maybe take each consecutive 4 letters, i.e., {aabc, eefg, eebd, aabb, ceef, fghd, cbbe, efbb, bbgh, hie} to make the tree?